# Sequelize findAndCountAll pagination issue

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

When using `findAndCountAll` with a limit and offset, I get only (for example) 8 rows per page instead of 10.

Here's what I'm using to paginate results (10 per page):

```js
async function allPlayers(req, res) {
  const page = parseInt(req.query.page);
  const perPage = parseInt(req.query.perPage);

  const options = {
    where: {
      [Op.and]: [
        {
          type: "player",
        },
        {
          "$teams.team.type$": "club",
        },
      ],
    },
    include: [
      {
        model: UserTeam,
        duplicating: false,
        required: true,
        include: [
          {
            model: Team,
            include: [{ model: Club }, { model: School }],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  };

  const { rows, count } = await User.findAndCountAll({
    ...options,
    limit: perPage,
    offset: perPage * (page - 1),
  });

  res.json({ data: { rows, count } });
}
```

The issue seems to be Sequelize filtering out the rows when returned from SQL, instead of in the query. This happens because of this segment in the find options query:

```js
{
  model: UserTeam,
  duplicating: false,
  required: true,
  include: [...],
}
```

Because of that, instead of returning 10 per paginated page, it's returning 10 or less (depending if any rows were filtered out).

Is there a fix for this behaviour or a different way to re-structure my data so I don't need this nested query?

I need this because I have a database/model structure like this:

```
User (players, coaches, admins, etc.)
  |
  |_ UserTeam (pivot table containing userId and teamId)
    |
    |_ Team
```

Comment: Actually, I have also faced an issue like this, when using some searching logic with a few includes, and searching by the included models parameters, filters, counting, and so on  I have tried a lot of things but no exact result. Some of my changes fixed some problems but created new ones. I have solved that problem by SQL query usage.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to reference the pivot/join tables in the query itself. There are too many nested levels of entities in your query with School and Club etc.

If you, instead of including the nested data when you perform the query, include the User/Player model and Team model in the UserTeam model with the reference keyword, Sequelize in my experience will handle this type of operation better. The same goes for School and Club, they could be included in their join tables' model definitions instead.

Note that I use the define method and not the class based models. What if you try something like this:

```js
    const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize')
    const sequelize = require('./../config/db')
    const User = require('./User')
    const Team = require('./Team')
    
    const UserTeam = sequelize.define('userTeam', {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false
      },
      teamId: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: false,
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        references: {
          model: Team,
          key: 'id'
        },
        validate: {
          isUUID: {
            args: 4,
            msg: 'Team ID must be a UUID4 string.'
          }
        }
      },
      userId: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: false,
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        references: {
          model: User,
          key: 'id'
        },
        validate: {
          isUUID: {
            args: 4,
            msg: 'User ID must be a UUID4 string.'
          }
        }
      },
      deletedAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: null
      }
    },
    {
      paranoid: true,
      tableName: 'userTeam'
    })
```

Then you include the Team like this:

```js
    const users = await User.findAll({
      include: Team
    })
```

Associations (it would probably be more logical to call the join table TeamUser and not UserTeam):

```js
User.belongsToMany(Team, { through: UserTeam, foreignKey: 'userId', onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
Team.belongsToMany(User, { through: UserTeam, foreignKey: 'teamId', onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
```

A json response based on this many-to-many relationship and the query above should result in a list of all users with every team that user is connected to. Here is one of those users:

```json
{
    "fullName": "Player One",
    "id": "6e8ca258-9daa-4d52-b033-a077d98c29ef",
    "firstName": "Player",
    "lastName": "One",
    "email": "playerone@gmail.com",
    "password": "$2a$14$tApwpX9Ld9a1cjZMFzTGZeVEUC01M7n/tSVlldG7OEbm9sEh/k8kW",
    "verified": 1,
    "verifyCode": "4f49b5ca-12ed5a2d-1608191096291",
    "resetPasswordToken": "bd15eda5097e030988eed5d2d20b3bbb6a06439f6b9907783fc0ea19083d8410",
    "resetPasswordExpire": 1620266644543,
    "passwordChangedAt": 1608337842942,
    "createdFromIp": "122.222.10.33",
    "createdAt": "2020-12-14T06:33:13.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-05-06T01:54:04.000Z",
    "deletedAt": null,
    "teams": [
        {
            "id": "427e9de4-9318-4406-aed9-fcbb3b8a3282",
            "name": "Texas Rangers",
            "type": "MLB",
            "slug": "texas-rangers",
            "createdByUserId": "6e8ca258-9daa-4d52-b033-a077d98c29ef",
            "createdAt": "2020-12-14T06:33:15.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-12-29T06:07:54.000Z",
            "deletedAt": null,
            "userTeams": {
                "id": 54,
                "teamId": "427e9de4-9318-4406-aed9-fcbb3b8a3282",
                "userId": "6e8ca258-9daa-4d52-b033-a077d98c29ef",
                "deletedAt": null,
                "createdAt": "2020-12-14T06:33:15.000Z",
                "updatedAt": "2020-12-14T06:33:15.000Z"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "cbff6df7-0e0c-4906-9e1c-54b569079d83",
            "name": "New York Yankees",
            "type": "MLB",
            "slug": "yankees",
            "createdByUserId": "16f38fc5-63d1-4285-8773-526720f9a506",
            "createdAt": "2020-12-14T23:57:11.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-07-06T06:08:35.000Z",
            "deletedAt": null,
            "userTeams": {
                "id": 55,
                "teamId": "cbff6df7-0e0c-4906-9e1c-54b569079d83",
                "userId": "6e8ca258-9daa-4d52-b033-a077d98c29ef",
                "deletedAt": null,
                "createdAt": "2020-12-14T23:57:11.000Z",
                "updatedAt": "2020-12-14T23:57:11.000Z"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The query needs to filter based on `user.type` and `team.type`. The `UserTeam` model references `userId` and `teamId`. Are you suggesting to put more columns into the `UserTeam` pivot table? This is not possible for my data structure, since the teams, clubs, and schools are separate models, and need to be linked through a pivot table. Maybe I'm not fully understanding what you're suggesting, but this is how I interpret it...

Comment: 1/2: The userId and teamId is all a pivot table needs, but if you reference the User and Team models and their `key` in the UserTeam model, you will have access to all the data in every column from both of them (including user.type and team.type) via Sequelize queries. If you query all Users and include Team like in my example above, you will – because of the magical references in the pivot model – get a SQL query that looks something like this:

Comment: 2/2: `SELECT `users`.`id` (...etc.) FROM `users` AS `users` LEFT OUTER JOIN ( `userTeam` AS `teams->userTeams` INNER JOIN `teams` AS `teams` ON `teams`.`id` = `teams->userTeams`.`orgId` AND (`teams->userTeams`.`deletedAt` IS NULL)) ON `users`.`id` = `teams->userTeams`.`userId` AND (`teams`.`deletedAt` IS NULL) WHERE(`users`.`deletedAt` IS NULL);`

Comment: Added the api response to my original answer, with the resulti from querying the user table as described above. If you follow this pattern you should have enough user data to work with in your filter.

Answer (score 0):

Let try this function bro

```
paginate: ({
        currentPage,
        pageSize
    }) => {
        const offset = parseInt((currentPage - 1) * pageSize, 10);
        const limit = parseInt(pageSize, 10);
        return {
            offset,
            limit,
        };
    },

    // import function here
    const result = await city.findAndCountAll({
        where: conditions,
        order: [
            ['createdAt', 'DESC']
        ],
        ...paginate({
            currentPage: page,
            pageSize: limit
        }),
    })
```

[image]